# Symfony - Disabling listener on docrine fixtures load

Tags: symfony, doctrine, listener, fixtures

I've seen there is already some questions on this issue, with answers solving it.

I've tried to implement those solutions but still am getting error.

Here is my Fixtures function:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        $em->getConfiguration()->getEntityListenerResolver()->clear(ParticularListener::class);

       // load stuff after 
}
```

There I'm trying to disable a particular listener. Even after cleaning the cache and everything the listener is still called.

As I want to load some data that the listener prevent from loading, the loading fail.

I need those data for testing, and do no really understand why this solution doesn't work here.

here is my `entityListener`:

```
class SomeEntityListener
{
    /**
     * @param EntityName $var
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function prePersist(EntityName $var, LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        if ($var->getStartDate() < new \DateTime()) {
            throw new MyAccessDeniedException('some error message');
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please show the Event listener class.

Comment: Do you want to disable all listeners or just one?

Comment: Only one, all of them wouldn't be an issue though given it's only to load fixtures. But the one or just `clear()` do not work